# How to make the sum of a column of an array on java

Tags: java

I have, for example, this array :

```
int s[][] = { {4,5},{2,7}};
```

I would like to calculate the sum of a column.

Comment: Start by reading [this](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html). This problem is quite simple to google, so please do some research of your own before asking on SO.

Answer (score 1):

For example like this:

```
int[][] array2D = {{4,5},{2,7}};
int column1 = 0;
int column2 = 0;
for(int[] array : array2D){
    column1 += array[0];
    column2 += array[1];
}
```

Comment: but if i want make a function ?

Comment: @am9511 what do you mean by function? you want to do it in separate method?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the one that works for any no. of columns and has reusable method

```
public class SumColumn {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    int s[][] = {{4,5,6},{2,7,6}};

    int[] sum = getSumofColumns(s) ;
    for(int i=0;i<sum.length;i++){
        System.out.println("sum of column "+(i+1)+" is "+ sum[i]);
    }
  }

  public static int[] getSumofColumns(int[][] s){
    int[] sum=new int[s[0].length];
        for(int i=0;i<s.length;i++){
            for(int j=0;j<s[i].length;j++){
                sum[j]+=s[i][j];
            }
        }
        return sum;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to add the sum of a particular column.

This might help you

1.Create a method which accepts the column number.

```
public int addcolumnn(int col)
```

2.Traverse through the rows and add the element at each `a[i][col]` where `i` is the `row index` and col is the `column index`

//Sample code

```
public int addcolumnn(int col)
{
    int sum=0;
    for(int i=0;i<numberofrows;i++)
    {
         sum+=arr[i][col];//arr is your array
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.Happy Coding!!